# BiBTeX style with hyperlinks and [key] citations

Tags: bibtex

I'm looking for a bibliography style with the following constraints:

1. Must generate a link if the `url` key is provided in the bibliography. (I can't change the `.bib` file.) Other than that I have no formatting guidelines on the appearance of entries. I don't even mind whether the URL is printed out or the title is made a link. This rules out the basic BibTeX styles, otherwise I'd use `alpha`.
2. Must produce citations with `\cite{entry-name}` that look like `[MA]` or `[MA42]` where `MA` is some kind of mnemonic abbreviation. Author initials are fine for documents where authors are meaningful, but not for documents such as technical manuals where the author is poorly-defined or irrelevant; such entries all have a `key` field that can be used as the abbreviation. Numbered citations are out (too uninformative) and author-date citations are out (many of the citations are technical documentation where the author is not relevant, and `(Author, 2016)` doesn't look like a citation to my target audience).
3. Must be available on my reference platform: Ubuntu 14.04 with the [`texlive-latex-recommended`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-latex-recommended/filelist) package (so the `.bst` file should be in either the [base](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-latex-base/filelist) or [recommended](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-latex-recommended/filelist) list). I might stretch this to [`texlive-latex-extra`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-latex-extra) and [`texlive-bibtex-extra`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-bibtex-extra) if I really need to, which would allow BibLaTeX (but note that it's a late 2013 version, not the latest and greatest) and urlbst, but I'd really prefer to keep the requirements small.
4. Must cope with an `annote` entry containing “weird” characters such as `%`. (Once again: it must work with my `.bib` files.) This rules out `babelbib`.

What are my options?

Sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@Manual{javase,
  title = {{Java Standard Edition 8 API Specification}},
  key = {Java8},
  organization = {Oracle},
  year = 2016,
  url = {http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/},
  annote = {100% annoying}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{javase}: [Jav16] is ok, [Java8] would be better, (Oracle, 2016) is right out

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Having an unescaped `%` character anywhere other than a URL string is going to create havoc: It's going to be treated as a comment character. Any reason why you can't write `\%`?

Comment: You may want to look into creating your own bespoke bibliography style, using the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. In particular, you'll be able to create an alphabetical citation call-out style that recognizes fields such as `url`. (By the way, to create hyperlinks, you'll also need to load the `hyperref` package.)